# NGINX Proxy Setup for ws:// protocol

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket

I am trying to setup NGINX to proxy web socket traffic. I am running a web page on NGINX (port 80) that has an MJPEG feed from port 8080 and also takes web socket traffic over port 8090. I can proxy the MJPEG stream, but not the web sockets. In my webpage, client side javascript was connecting fine without the proxy using this line:

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.14:8989/ws');

To proxy this I tried setting up the following NGINX config:

```
    #Proxy the Web Socket Traffic
    #----------------------------------------------
    location /sock/ {
        proxy_pass ws://localhost:8989/ws;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    #Proxy the MJPEG Streamer feed
    #----------------------------------------------
    location /mjpeg/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
```

And then changed the client side javascript to the following:

var conn = new WebSocket('http://192.168.0.14/sock/');

However when I restart of NGINX results in:

Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

If I change the proxy pass line to "proxy_pass http://localhost:8989/ws;" then the NGINX service restarts successfully but I can make a web socket connection anymore.

Is there anything else I need to configure so that NGINX will proxy to ws:// addresses? Is http:// equivalent if it is upgrading the protocol? If the latter is true, then why doesnt it work?

I notice in this post that they are using ws:// in the proxy pass statement. But it doesnt work for me [NGINX: How to proxy http(s) traffic to one server and ws(s) traffic to another?](https://serverfault.com/questions/630340/nginx-how-to-proxy-https-traffic-to-one-server-and-wss-traffic-to-another)

Comment: What does nginx error log show?

Comment: This is an answer by @lee-melbourne who posted it by editing the question itself...  Solution:

So I now have this working. You still need to use ws:// in the client side javascript to connect. NGINX will still pick that connection up and proxy it. So the client side js is:

`var conn = new WebSocket('ws:///sock/ws');`

And the proxy config is:

    
   `location /sock/ {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8989/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }`

Comment: @lee-melbourne ... please post it as an answer rather than editing the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No nginx documentation available mentions the `ws://` scheme as available to use in the config. No wonder the nginx fails to start, I bet it's the configuration error it's complaining about.

And you definitely have the [correct configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) for the websockets proxy. As about why it doesn't work - it's still up to determining, this can be due to large set of reasons: nobody really listens on the tcp/8989, or some application error in the listener happens.